# Java Open GUI and wait until its closed

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm trying to open a GUI and then wait until the JFrame is closed. I heard about JDialog but I don't know how to use it with my actual code:

```
GUI gui = new GUI();
gui.show(); // Creates some JButtons, JLabels, and show the JFrame.
```

Now I would like to wait until the JFrame is closed, but I don't know how to continue.

Can you help me please?

Comment: *"I heard about JDialog but I don't know how to use it with my actual code:"*  Then [find out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).  That will be easier than making a frame behave in a modal manner.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about 'using a hammer to tighten a screw' (use a screw driver).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

- Inherit from `JDialog` instead of `JFrame`.
- Call `setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL)` to make the dialog modal.
- If you currently use the `JFrame(LayoutManager)` constructor, you have to call `setLayout()` to set the `LayoutManager` instead.
- When you are done with your dialog, call `setVisible(false)` or `dispose` to continue with your program.

PS: Next time you should post working code that exposes your problem.